# Unable to add AppDomains in Outlook on send Add-in manifests

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm relatively new to developing Outlook add-ins, and am facing a problem developing an on-send add-in.

I am trying to do an ajax call from inside my on-send add-in like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://XXXXXXX.dev:9999/createMeeting",
    data: JSON.stringify(result),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("ERRROR", error)
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log("DONE ", data)
});
```

My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
    xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="MailApp">

    <AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>DOMAIN1</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>DOMAIN2</AppDomain>
    </AppDomains>

    <Id>XXXXXXXX-1a52-42a0-96bf-100d801a4ef7</Id>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-us</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="Contoso Subject and CC Checker" />
    <Description DefaultValue="Contoso Subject and CC Checker" />

    <Requirements>
        <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
            <Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>



    <FormSettings>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
            <DesktopSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://XXXXXXXX.dev:3001/index.html" />
            </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
    </FormSettings>

    <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>

    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    </Rule>

    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <!-- On Send requires VersionOverridesV1_1 -->
        <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
            <Description resid="residAppDescription" />
            <Requirements>
                <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
                    <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
                </bt:Sets>
            </Requirements>

            <Hosts>
                <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                    <DesktopFormFactor>
                        <!-- The functionfile and function name to call on message send.  -->
                        <!-- In this particular case the function validateSubjectAndCC will be called within the JavaScript code referenced in residUILessFunctionFileUrl. -->
                        <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
                            <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateSubjectAndCC" />
                        </ExtensionPoint>
                    </DesktopFormFactor>
                </Host>
            </Hosts>
            <Resources>
                <bt:Urls>
                    <!-- The JavaScript code is hosted on a secure and trusted web server. -->
                    <bt:Url id="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" DefaultValue="https://XXXXXXXX.dev:3001/index.html"></bt:Url>
                </bt:Urls>
            </Resources>
        </VersionOverrides>
    </VersionOverrides>

</OfficeApp>
```

But I keep getting this error when I try to add the add-in

```
This app can't be installed. 
The manifest file doesn't conform to the schema definition. 
The element 'OfficeApp' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' has invalid child element 'AppDomains' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1'. 
List of possible elements expected: 'Id' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1'... 
The element 'OfficeApp' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' has invalid child element 'AppDomains' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1'. 
List of possible elements expected: 'Id' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1'.
```

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/manifests#app-domains), The **AppDomains** element must be a child of the **OfficeApp** element.
Am I doing something wrong??
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
This occurs on Outlook OWA (web) and Windows application. Have not verified on other platforms.

Comment: You should start with a template manifest and go from there.  At the top of that article that you linked is a manifest you can start with.  You are already missing some required elements that are in that template (IconUrl, SupportUrl, Hosts, etc.)  That template did not have AppDomains for some reason, but I think you put it too high in the document.  In our manifest AppDomains is after SupportUrl and before Hosts.  Also make sure that the domain name is fully qualified with the protocol, i.e. begins with https.

Comment: Also can you please mention which platform are you experiencing this? Is it on windows (outlook client), outlook web, mac or any other mobile platforms?

Comment: @BrianClink . I did I started with the template that comes with this [repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send)

[Manifest](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send/blob/master/outlook-add-in-on-send/Contoso%20Subject%20and%20CC%20Checker.xml)

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT . This occurs on Outlook OWA (web) and Windows application. Have not verified on other platforms. I'm stuck on this quite badly! :(

Comment: I took that sample from the repo link you posted, and added the AppDomains after the Description and before the Requirements.  It did have a positive effect as without the AppDomains it seemed to die in a CORS preflight request.  Note that there is a potential timing issue here, once you return either mailboxItem.notificationMessages.addAsync or asyncResult.asyncContext.completed or both, it seems the app will end/close, so you have to structure the code not to set the message or completed status until your Ajax call is returned / handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is caused due to the order in which you are adding the elements in manifest. As manifest file follows the schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" it expects elements in certain order mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-owemxml/00e4ee5d-2eb8-47f2-9008-8beb6ff45189). If you follow the order of elements mentioned in sample [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1#specify-domains-you-want-to-open-in-the-add-in-window) it should work fine.

Updated the links again.

Comment: It seems like the links are broken, I am unable to access the resources. Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: Updated the broken links. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an example in case anyone else has the same problem.

Thanks to Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
    xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="MailApp">

    <Id>XXXXXX-1a52-XXXXXX-96bf-XXXXXX</Id>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-us</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="Contoso Subject and CC Checker" />
    <Description DefaultValue="Contoso Subject and CC Checker" />

    <AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>https://www.XXXXXX.dev</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>https://XXXXXX.dev</AppDomain>
    </AppDomains>

    <Requirements>
        <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
            <Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>


    <FormSettings>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
            <DesktopSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://XXXXXX.dev:3001/index.html" />
            </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
    </FormSettings>

    <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>

    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    </Rule>

    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <!-- On Send requires VersionOverridesV1_1 -->
        <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
            <Description resid="residAppDescription" />
            <Requirements>
                <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
                    <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
                </bt:Sets>
            </Requirements>


            <Hosts>
                <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                    <DesktopFormFactor>
                        <!-- The functionfile and function name to call on message send.  -->
                        <!-- In this particular case the function validateSubjectAndCC will be called within the JavaScript code referenced in residUILessFunctionFileUrl. -->
                        <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
                            <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateSubjectAndCC" />
                        </ExtensionPoint>
                    </DesktopFormFactor>
                </Host>
            </Hosts>
            <Resources>
                <bt:Urls>
                    <!-- The JavaScript code is hosted on a secure and trusted web server. -->
                    <bt:Url id="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" DefaultValue="https://XXXXXX:3001/index.html"></bt:Url>
                </bt:Urls>
            </Resources>
        </VersionOverrides>
    </VersionOverrides>

</OfficeApp>
```